# How to get equivalent behavior of Keras tuner RandomSearch when using Dask

Tags: dask, keras-tuner

I have an existing hyperparameter search in Keras using `kerastuner.tuners.RandomSearch`.  It looks like this:

```
tuner = RandomSearch(build_model,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_trials=18,
    executions_per_trial=3,
)
```

I look at [dask documentation](https://ml.dask.org/modules/api.html#module-dask_ml.model_selection) and I don't see any equivalent call, particularly for specifying the objective as 'val_loss'.  Is there an equivalent in dask to the above statement?  My goal is to (see if) speed up the tuner search process.